# How to customize the renders in prefuse. Problem in customize images in prefuse layout

Tags: java, visualization, prefuse

HI all,

I have written a java application to show the images in different layouts.  I am able to show it different layout correctly but some times the images are overlapped.  In my application having more than 20/30 nodes and couple of nodes having 6 to 10 edges. The images size are 50*50. Because of the 10 edges, the nodes will overlapped i.e images will overlapped on another images. How can I solve the problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My code is given below

```
 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import java.util.;
import java.io.;
import java.awt.Font;
```

import prefuse.Constants;
import prefuse.Display;
import prefuse.Visualization;
import prefuse.action.ActionList;
import prefuse.action.RepaintAction;
import prefuse.action.assignment.ColorAction;
import prefuse.action.assignment.FontAction;
import prefuse.action.assignment.DataColorAction;
import prefuse.action.layout.graph.ForceDirectedLayout;
import prefuse.action.layout.graph.*;
import prefuse.action.layout.*;
import prefuse.activity.Activity;
import prefuse.controls.DragControl;
import prefuse.controls.PanControl;
import prefuse.controls.ZoomControl;
import prefuse.data.Graph;
import prefuse.data.io.DataIOException;
import prefuse.data.io.GraphMLReader;
import prefuse.render.DefaultRendererFactory;
import prefuse.render.LabelRenderer;
import prefuse.util.ColorLib;
import prefuse.visual.VisualItem;
import prefuse.visual.*;
import prefuse.util.FontLib;
import prefuse.action.assignment.DataSizeAction;

import prefuse.data.*;
import prefuse.render.ImageFactory;

public class LayoutExample {

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Graph graph = null;
    try {

        graph = new GraphMLReader().readGraph("/graphs.xml");
    } catch ( DataIOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error loading graph. Exiting...");
        System.exit(1);
    }

ImageFactory imageFactory = new ImageFactory(100,100);

try
{
    //load images and construct imageFactory.
    String images[] = new String[3];
    images[0] = "data/images/switch.png";
    images[1] = "data/images/ip_network.png";
    images[2] = "data/images/router.png";

    String[] names = new String[] {"Switch","Network","Router"};
    BufferedImage img = null;

    for(int i=0; i < images.length ; i++)
    {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(images[i]));
            imageFactory.addImage(names[i],img);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }
    }


}
catch(Exception exp)
{

}


    Visualization vis = new Visualization();
    vis.add("graph", graph);

LabelRenderer nodeRenderer = new LabelRenderer("name", "type");
    nodeRenderer.setVerticalAlignment(Constants.BOTTOM);
    nodeRenderer.setHorizontalPadding(0);
    nodeRenderer.setVerticalPadding(0);
    nodeRenderer.setImagePosition(Constants.TOP);
    nodeRenderer.setMaxImageDimensions(100,100); 

    DefaultRendererFactory drf = new DefaultRendererFactory();
    drf.setDefaultRenderer(nodeRenderer);
    vis.setRendererFactory(drf); 

    ColorAction nText = new ColorAction("graph.nodes", VisualItem.TEXTCOLOR);
    nText.setDefaultColor(ColorLib.gray(100));


    ColorAction nEdges = new ColorAction("graph.edges", VisualItem.STROKECOLOR);
    nEdges.setDefaultColor(ColorLib.gray(100));

    // bundle the color actions
    ActionList draw = new ActionList();

     //MAD - changing the size of the nodes dependent on the weight of the people
    final DataSizeAction dsa = new DataSizeAction("graph.nodes","size");        
    draw.add(dsa);

    draw.add(nText);
    draw.add(new FontAction("graph.nodes", FontLib.getFont("Tahoma",Font.BOLD, 12)));
    draw.add(nEdges);

    vis.putAction("draw", draw);



  ActionList layout = new ActionList(Activity.DEFAULT_STEP_TIME);


  BalloonTreeLayout balloonlayout = new BalloonTreeLayout("graph",50);
  layout.add(balloonlayout); 


    Display d = new Display(vis);

    vis.putAction("layout", layout);


// start up the animated layout
    vis.run("draw");
vis.run("layout");


    d.addControlListener(new DragControl());
    // pan with left-click drag on background
    d.addControlListener(new PanControl()); 
    // zoom with right-click drag
    d.addControlListener(new ZoomControl()); 

    // -- 6. launch the visualization -------------------------------------






    // create a new window to hold the visualization
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("prefuse example");
    // ensure application exits when window is closed
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(d);
    frame.pack();           // layout components in window
    frame.setVisible(true); // show the window

}
```

}

Thanks
R.Ravikumar